# Trouble understanding solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,\;b,\; c$ be integer side lengths of a triangle. Show that if the equation
$$x^2+(a+1)x+b-c=0$$
has integer roots, then the triangle is isosceles.

---

Solution: "If $b>c$ then $(a+1)^2-4(b-c)$ is a perfect square, it is smaller than $(a+1)^2$, and it is the same parity as $(a+1)^2$. Hence
$$(a+1)^2-4(b-c)\leq (a-1)^2.$$
Therefore $a+c\leq b$, which violates the triangle inequality. Similarly, $b<c$ is also false. Therefore $b=c$."

I'm most confused on how they form $(a-1)^2$. If someone could explain what they are doing there, it would help a lot.

Comment: What triangle are you referring to?

Comment: @AdamHughes based on OP's solution, I'd guess he's referring to the triangle withe the sides $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: Edited accordingly. Sorry

Comment: Do you know how to solve an equation with $x^2$ in it? For example, what are the roots for $3x^2+2x+1=0$? Or more importantly, what do you use to find these roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the roots are integer, $$(a+1)^2-4(b-c)$$ is a perfect square. If for example, $(a+1)^2$ is even, then so are $(a-1)^2$ and $(a+1)^2-4(b-c)$. But $(a-1)^2$ and $(a+1)^2$ are **two consecutive even perfect squares**. So, as an even perfect square, $(a+1)^2-4(b-c)$ can not lie between them. Consequently, $$(a+1)^2-4(b-c)\leq (a-1)^2$$.

The same reasoning can be applied to the case where $(a+1)^2$ is odd.

Comment: This clears up my confusion! Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the assumption that the solutions to $x^2+(a+1)x+b-c=0$ are integers. Recall the quadratic formula: given the quadratic equation $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$, we have

$$x=\frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$

Since $x$ is an integer, what can you deduce from this formula?